# Парсер не скачивает файл и неправильно формирует ссылку

Tags: php, парсер

Веду музыкальный сайт. Он парсит музыку с другого сайта. Сейчас перестал работать.
Как было: mp3-файл парсился со стороннего сайта, файл закачивался во временную папку с правами 777 - tmp. Прямая ссылка со стороннего сайта заменялась на прямую ссылку с моего сайта. Теперь этого не происходит

ПРОБЛЕМА в чём:  Прямая ссылка со стороннего сайта так и пишется в мою БД, не преобразовывается. mp3-файл не закачивается.
При этом в логах появилась ошибка - `Cannot modify header information - headers already sent`

Обработчик имеет следующий вид:

```
// пишем песню с парсера

include ('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html($linkmp3);
if($html && is_object($html) && isset($html->nodes)){
   foreach($html->find('a.download_link') as $link){
      $file_link = $link[0]->href;
$file_title = basename($link[0]->href);
$file_title = str_ireplace('othersite.ru' , 'mysite.com', $file_title);
// копируем в локальную папку
chmod('tmp/'.$file_title, 0777);
copy ( $file_link , 'tmp/'.$file_title);
// собираем инфу на формирование тегов
$mp3_tags = array();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT title FROM style WHERE id=" . (int)$style_id,$db);
if ($result)
{
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $mp3_tags["genre"] = $row["title"];
    }
}
$title_parts = explode(' - ', $title);
$mp3_tags["artist"] = $title_parts[0];
$mp3_tags["title"] = $title_parts[1];
$mp3_tags["year"] = $year;
$mp3_tags["album"] = date("Y, F");
$mp3_tags["comment"] = "http://mysite.com";

// заменяем теги
replace_mp3_tags('tmp/'.$file_title, $mp3_tags);
//die();

// переносим
$new_path = 'plus/' . date("ymd") . '/' . $file_title;
$new_rel_path = '../' . $new_path;
// рекурсивно создает папки, если их нет
if (!is_dir(dirname($new_rel_path))) {
    mkdir(dirname($new_rel_path), 0777, true);
}
rename("tmp/" . $file_title, $new_rel_path);

// обновляем
$linkmp3 = $preview = $new_path;


if (isset($title)) 
{
// если поля не пустые и такой песни нет - заносим новую песню в базу - в таблицу song_add
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO song_add (title)VALUES ('$title')");         
$new_song_result = mysql_query("SELECT max(id) AS new_id FROM song_add", $db); // запрос на поиск номера только что добавленной песни 
$new_song_row = mysql_fetch_array($new_song_result); // достаем строку
$new_song_id = $new_song_row["new_id"]; // получаем номер только что добавленной песни
// и вот теперь мы добавляем в таблицу files значение с нужной айди песни, тоесть:
$result2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO files (linkmp3,id) VALUES ('$linkmp3','$new_song_id')");
if ($result == 'true'){
    echo "Песня успешно добавлена<br>";
    if ($result2 == 'true'){echo "Ссылка к песне добавлена тоже";}
}

else {mysql_error();} 
}
               else {echo "Заполнены не все поля!<br>Песня НЕ добавлена";}

$result = mysql_query("UPDATE parsed SET  (is_processed = 1) WHERE id=" . $id);
   }
}
```

(не нашёл, как оформить php код в BB-теги)

Answer (score 1):

Вы пытаетесь передать клиенту заголовки (Headers) после того, как вывелась информация в тело ответа. Это могло произойти, если выполнен echo или notice до того, как был запущен session_start или header()

Comment: Похоже, приведенный код - это не все, что участвует в выполнении.

Comment: да, Это конечно не весь обработчик, а та часть, где появляется ошибка

Comment: На какой строке?

Comment: Проблема в том, что изменения произошли со стороннего сайта (с которого берётся инфа). Теперь переход на ссылку не дает новую страницу а сразу отдает файл. И парсить теперь там нечего. Просто нужно копировать себе файл и с ним проводить операции. При переходе на ссылку получаем файл. Работа с файлом вызывает затруднения. На какой строке ошибка - сказать не могу, т.к. в логах ошибка - header already sent. Возможно в коде неверно поставлены две последние закрывающиеся фигурные скобки   - в самом конце }
}

Comment: В таком случае просто качайте файл себе и проводите над ним операции.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22155882/php-curl-download-file